# Android attach specific file

Tags: java, android, attachment

Am working on an application in which I'd need to have a checkbox which when checked attaches a specific file from the SD card say, 'image1.jpg'. Anyone know how I can implement this?

Comment: add a listener man and try to acces file inside that.

Answer (score 0):

You can hava an ImageView under your checkbox, and the visibility of this ImageView is GONE when checkbox is not checked by invoking bellow:

```
ImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

When checkbox is checked, you can change the visibility by the same method with another arg View.VISIBLE. Then you can display your image in ImageView.
If ImageView is not your need, change it.